# Rewrite results (like trimming titles) won't work at all

Tags: views

I created a view with articles. All I need is to trim titles.
The reason I cannot do this from content types (teaser view) is because the title field is a node module element. (It cannot be deleted, and is too late for that.)

There is an option in views output in the preview mode/contextual menus/rewrite results, but it seems it won't work.

[image: screenshot]

None of the rewrite results options will work. It looks like a bug in the Views module.

Comment: Try to increase the maximum length, then it will work

Answer (score 2):

Clear your Drupal cache by visiting **/admin/config/development/performance** or if you use the [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) module, simply run `drush cc all`

Also make sure you're editing and viewing the correct view.  If you're modify the master display but viewing an overwritten display, your master view settings will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully trim node titles to 5 characters using the controls you show above.The following view normally produces 'SR 1-1, SR 1-2, SR 1-3'. With trimming enabled I get:

[image: Node titles trimmed to 5 characters]

I used versions: drupal-7.9, ctools-7.x-1.0-rc1, views-7.x-3.0-rc1. Perhaps you need to upgrade your views or ctools modules. When you upgrade any module, always be sure to run update.php.